# Definition of a relatively closed set in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

What is the definition of a relatively closed set in real analysis (without using terms of topology)?

I use 'Lehrbuch der Analysis' of Heuser (original text is in German) for learning. The book defines a relatively open set as below (on page 224 as a part of task 6):

> Let X a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. $F \subset X$ is said to be X-closed or relatively closed, when the limit of each sequence in F, which converges to an element of X, even lies in F.

Is there, for instance, an alternative definition or a rephrasing for above definition?

Comment: I tried to find another definition in the internet, but was difficult to find one, which does not use terms of topology.

The difficulty can be also in the phrasing. This sentenses use several subsentenses, which probably makes it difficult to understand.

Comment: I do not see what the point of your question is. You give a defintion of relatively closed, and ask for what?

Comment: @martini Can you give me, for instance a rephrasing or couple of example of relatively closed sets?

Comment: If i am not wrong a subset of $X$ is relatively closed if and only if it is closed in relative topology on $X$.

Comment: @Kulisty can an explanation be given without concepts of topology, but only of words in real analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Relatively closed* in $X$ can be defined by restriction of usual characterisations of "closed" to $X$, recall that a set $A \subseteq \mathbf R$ is closed iff one of the following is true:

> (a) For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ that converges, say $x_n \to x$, we have $x \in A$.
>
> (b) If $y \not\in A$, then there is $\def\eps{\epsilon}\eps > 0$ such that $(y-\eps, y+\epsilon) \cap A = \emptyset$

When we "restrict to $X$", we have that a set $A \subseteq X$ is relatively closed in $X$, iff

> (a) For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ that converges **in $X$**, say $x_n \to x \in X$, we have $x \in A$.
>
> (b) If $y \in X \setminus A$, then there is $\def\eps{\epsilon}\eps > 0$ such that $(y-\eps, y+\epsilon) \cap A = \emptyset$

To give examples:

1. $(0,1]$ is relatively closed in $(0,\infty)$.
2. $(0,1]$ is not relatively closed in $(-1,\infty)$.
3. $\{\frac 1n\mid n \in \mathbf N\}$ is relatively closed in $(0,1]$.
4. If $A$ is any closed set, and $X \subseteq \mathbf R$ is arbitrary, then $A \cap X$ is relatively closed in $X$.

Comment: So, (a) of the definition of a closed set means that '$F \subset X$ is relatively closed in X, when not necessarily every sequence of F, but all sequences in F which converges to $x \in X$ have limits in F', correct?

Comment: Should not we also need 'one of the following is true' for the definition of relative closedness?